# Ajax enabled WCF service. How to return complex object from service call?

Tags: wcf

Ajax enabled WCF service. How to return complex object from service call? 
It fails when try to return any complex object that is not primitive like int, string .etc.
Is it possible at all? I can't find any sample. All samples are with primitive signatures.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[DataContract]` attribute over class declaration and `[DataMember]` over properties should do the trick.